# why is the eye mesh moving after i join the rigs?

Tags: rigging

I have created a dragon and have it rigged. the eyes are separate with its own rig and when i try to join the 2 together the eyes move to a different location.[![before joining
[[image: ][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgULN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaXrA.png)

Comment: do you mean you join the 2 armatures? maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: yes when i join them the eyes move to a different area.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6171" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6171/)

Comment: to make the things easier, maybe also join the bones, then parent the eyes bones to the head bone, check if the eyes are only controlled by the eyes bones, etc...

Comment: that is what i am trying to do. the eyes are parented to the eye bones and all the constraints work. his eyes blink and move. then i have the body parented to the body bones and everything moves right, but when i try to join the eye and body bones the actual eyes move to another location and the eye bones do not control the eyes. it makes no since to me

Comment: select the eyes, then the body, then ctrl J. After that, select the eyes armature, then the body armature, then ctrl J. It works, the eyes don't go crazy. Of course you still need to parent everything correctly.

Comment: that is so awsome. thank you. now i have to try and figure out why when i move the mesh in object mode one of the eye balls goes the other direction. its like a mirror but i dont have any mirror modifiers

Comment: I don't know what's happening precisely but when an object is parented to an armature, its shape is affected by the bones influence. If you don't want to see the effect of the armature on your object, maybe go in the modifiers and disable the display in viewport option.